# Which activation functions are available in RSNNS package apart from Logistic?

Tags: r, neural-network

The CRAN document on RSNNS only mentions Act_Logistic as an example for hidden layer activation function. Is there a list of all available activation functions in RSNNS somewhere?

I was specifically looking for syntax for hyperbolic tangent function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know for sure whether all the activation functions from the original SNNS are available in RSNNS, but you find a list of all those activation functions in the following document (page 249):

http://www.ra.cs.uni-tuebingen.de/downloads/SNNS/SNNSv4.2.Manual.pdf

Answer (score 5):

yes, most (all?) of these functions are available in RSNNS. You can get a list with:

```
library(RSNNS)
RSNNS::getSnnsRFunctionTable()
```